# Table structure for data with many NULLs

Tags: sql, database

I'm currently trying to model a dynamic data object that can have or miss some properties (the property names are known for the current requirement). It is not known if new properties will be added later on (but it is almost certain). The modeled object is something along the line of this:

```
int id PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL;
int owner FOREIGN KEY NOT NULL;
Date date NOT NULL;
Time time NOT NULL;
Map<String,String> properties;
```

A property can be of any type ( int, bool, string,... )

I'm not sure how i should model this object in an SQL database. There are 2 ways i can think of to do this and i would like to have some input which will be the better choice in terms of developer "work"(maintenance), memory consumption and performance. As a side info: properties are almost always NULL (not existant)

(1) I would have a big table that has id, owner, date, time and every property as a column whereas missing properties for a row are modeled as NULL. e.g.

```
TABLE_X
id|owner|date|time|prop_1|prop_2|prop_3|...
```

This table would have alot of NULL values.

If new properties should be added then i would do an ALTER TABLE and insert a new column for every new property

Here i would do a "usual"

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_X ...
```

(2) I would have a main table with all NOT NULL data:

```
TABLE_X
id|owner|date|time
```

And then have a seperate table for every property, like this:

```
TABLE_X_PROP_N
foreign_key(TABLE_X(id))|value
```

Here would be no NULL values at all. A property either has a value and is in its corresponding table or it is NULL and then does not appear in its table.

To add new properties i would just add another table.

Here is would do a

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_X LEFT JOIN TABLE_X_PROP_1 ON ... LEFT JOIN TABLE_X_PROP_2 ON ...
```

To repeat the question (so you don't have to scroll up):
Which of boths ways to deal with the problem is the better in terms of maintenance (work for developer), memory consumption (on disk) and performance (more queries per second)? Maybe you also have a better idea on how to deal with this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go with Option 2, I would think you need 3 tables:

TABLE_HEADER
id|owner|date|time

TABLE_PROPERTY
id|name

TABLE_PROPERTYVALUE
id|headerID(FK)|propertyID(FK)|value

Easy to add new properties allow you greater flexibility and to iterate much faster. The number of properties would also have an effect (for example if you have 500 properties you aren't going to want a table with 500 columns!). The main downside is it will become ugly if you need to attach complex business logic using the properties as its a more complex structure to navigate and you can't enforce data integrity like not null for particular fields. If you truly want a property bag like you have modeled in your object structure then this maps easily. **Like everything it depends on your circumstances for what is most suitable.**

Comment: similar to my comment to arturros answer i'm not sure how to retrieve a specific property value if i have multiple properties for an id in TABLE_HEADER.
Visually when *I* LEFT JOIN they would be next to each other, but would this also be when  a DB Engine does this? can't the columns not be in random order? 
Example:
    id1|owner1|date1|time1|id_propName1|name1|id_propValue1|id_propName1|id1|value1|id_propName2|name2|id_propValue2|id_propName2|id1|value2 
-> how would i get the value for prop_2 out of this result?

Comment: @Nogiax - Your object structure (Map<String,String> properties;) indicates you want to hold the properties in a property bag i.e. rows. Which would lend itself to option 2. This assumes that you are not doing joins and instead would do 2 small queries, one for the header and 1 for the properties and you logic is all in your code rather than the database. If you want to join the properties to make a a single row i.e. properties as columns then you may as well go with option 1 as it will be much easier to query.

Comment: Thanks to you explanation. Your approach sounds sensible. i have a follow up question: If i select all rows from TABLE_HEADER and the number of rows retrieved would be X. Then i would like to get the properties for every row. Wouln'td this result in X additional requests to get all properties for all objects ( so it is 1+X queries for all data)?

Comment: @Nogiax - No you don't need to get them one header at a time, you could easily select all rows from the propertyvalue table (or more likely a subset) - this is basic sql with a where clause. You could then iterate over the rows and carve them up as needed in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 2. but why without separate tables for every property. Just put everything in one table:

```
properties(
foreign_key(TABLE_X(id))
property_name,
value);
```

Comment: This could be an idea but i'm not sure how to distinguish a value of prop_1 from a value of prop_2? In my second solution i could name the "value" column of a property like the name of the property and thus when i join the tables the value is associated with the column name. But how would this work with your solution?
Edit: I'm really new to this. I'm sorry if it is "obvious" how this works with your solution

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're trying to implement an Entity-Attribute-Value (often-viewed-as-an-anti-)pattern here.  Are you familiar with them?  Here's a few references:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/93124/eav-is-it-really-bad-in-all-scenarios

http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1619660-OTLT-EAV-design-why-do-people-hate-it

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Personally I'm extremely wary of this type of setup in a RDBMS.  I tend to think that NoSQL document style databases would be a better fit for these types of dynamic structures, though admittedly I have relatively little real-world experience with NoSQL myself.

Comment: The accepted answer of your first link doesn't say anything about an anti-pattern. It rightly (IMO) states that it has benefits as well as trade-offs which a developer needs to judge against their unique circumstances. Similarly your third article does not deem it an anti-pattern.

Comment: @Daniel - I don't disagree... my use of the (anti-) was more to note that it is often viewed as an antipattern and to raise some awareness to the fact that there is a considerable set of tradeoffs to be aware of, rather than to have marked it as one myself.

Comment: @jdl134679 - thanks, i will have a look at your references.